# How to store data without a database in a WPF MVVM software?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

This is a tool which supports import and export and many other features. I want to store the data without using any database. How can I do this?

a. How shall i arrange my classes?
b. Is serializing and storing in JSON is the only format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange your classes as you need to based on your requirements. Think about a NoSQL database view of things if you're serializing objects, such that, for example, companies have people, people have managers, and people perform tasks, so something a little like:

```cs
public class Company
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a JSON serializer. JSON.NET is the most popular by far and supports many customizable behaviors, as well as references. In the example above, you wouldn't want a deep duplication of a Person that was a Manager, and their Manager, and so on. So JSON.NET supports references. Documentation is available at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

However, if you're not going to use a NoSQL database, you're also missing out on backup capabilities, transactions, etc. You should think about creating a backup of the previous 1 or more files before saving a new one, deleting older ones as necessary. Or just use a NoSQL database that runs locally (there are many options) and maybe even has online sync capabilities if you want to support multiple users.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mr Heath. We did use JSON serialisation and deserialisation. It's working fine now. As you said we are now focusing on having a backup to support save/cancel/undo properties. Any further heads up regarding backup is appreciated! Thankyou.